# Realistic data generator package available for Django

Tags: python, django

I have created a dummy app. I want to insert some fake entries in my `models.User` models (fake entries should be valuable text, not be a random text). Is any Django package available for generating fake entries?

I have spent lots of my time searching for Django packages that generate fake entries. I found a Python library, `fake-factory`, for generating fake data, but with that we need to create every field manually, I don't want this. Is there any solution instead of this?

Comment: You can very easily get tens of thousands of users in bulk free of charge from http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/order.php

They supply as CSV, PostgreSQL scripts and numerous others. 

You should have no difficulty importing into a database created according to Nima's recommended methos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to try `Mixer`. It Provides `fakers` tool to generate most of the useful items for database.

if this is you user model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(255))
    country = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

you query will be:

```
from mixer import fakers as f
from models import User

name = f.get_name()
country = f.get_country()
email = f.get_email()
city = f.get_city()

s = db.session
user = User(name=name, email=email, city=city, country=country)
s.add(user)
s.commit()
s.close()
```

You can more details Here :

https://mixer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fakers.html

Comment: Thanks @Nima i am trying it...